# How remove data dependency in RK4 method Open MP C++

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm trying to write parallel code for Runge-Kutta 4th order.

For this goal i use Open MP and try parallelize general loop. In first version i use summarize array in second version reduction sum. Spoiler: All version don't work correct

First version

```
    startT = omp_get_wtime();

    omp_set_num_threads(4);

#pragma omp parallel shared(x0, y0, z0)
    {
        int rank = omp_get_thread_num();
        size = omp_get_num_threads();


        double
            uK1, uK2, uK3, uK4,
            vK1, vK2, vK3, vK4,
            wK1, wK2, wK3, wK4,
            xK1, xK2, xK3, xK4,
            yK1, yK2, yK3, yK4,
            zK1, zK2, zK3, zK4,
            x1, x2, x3, x4,
            y1, y2, y3, y4,
            z1, z2, z3, z4;

        double
            private_u[N] = {},
            private_v[N] = {}, 
            private_w[N] = {},
            private_x[N] = {},
            private_y[N] = {},
            private_z[N] = {};

        if (rank == 0)
        {
            private_x[0] = 5.0;
            private_y[0] = 0.8 * (bz + Rp) / 2.0;
            private_z[0] = 0.8 * (bz + Rp) / 2.0;
            private_u[0] = -Vt;
            private_v[0] = 0;
            private_w[0] = 0;
        }


#pragma omp for private(i)
        for (i = 0; i < N - 1 ; i++)
        {
            x1 = private_x[i];
            y1 = private_y[i];
            z1 = private_z[i];

            getK1K2K3K4(x0, y0, z0, epsm, sig, x1, y1, z1, &uK1, &vK1, &wK1);

            xK1 = private_u[i];
            yK1 = private_v[i];
            zK1 = private_w[i];

            x2 = x1 + dt / 2.0 * xK1;
            y2 = y1 + dt / 2.0 * yK1;
            z2 = z1 + dt / 2.0 * zK1;


            xK2 = xK1 + dt / 2.0 * uK1;
            yK2 = yK1 + dt / 2.0 * vK1;
            zK2 = zK1 + dt / 2.0 * wK1;

            getK1K2K3K4(x0, y0, z0, epsm, sig, x2, y2, z2, &uK2, &vK2, &wK2);


            x3 = x1 + dt / 2.0 * xK2;
            y3 = y1 + dt / 2.0 * yK2;
            z3 = z1 + dt / 2.0 * zK2;


            xK3 = xK1 + dt / 2.0 * uK2;
            yK3 = yK1 + dt / 2.0 * vK2;
            zK3 = zK1 + dt / 2.0 * wK2;


            getK1K2K3K4(x0, y0, z0, epsm, sig, x3, y3, z3, &uK3, &vK3, &wK3);

            x4 = x1 + dt * xK3;
            y4 = y1 + dt * yK3;
            z4 = z1 + dt * zK3;

            xK4 = xK1 + dt * uK3;
            yK4 = yK1 + dt * vK3;
            zK4 = zK1 + dt * wK3;

            getK1K2K3K4(x0, y0, z0, epsm, sig, x4, y4, z4, &uK4, &vK4, &wK4);

            private_x[i + 1] = private_x[i] + dt / 6.0 * (xK1 + 2.0 * xK2 + 2.0 * xK3 + xK4);
            private_y[i + 1] = private_y[i] + dt / 6.0 * (yK1 + 2.0 * yK2 + 2.0 * yK3 + yK4);
            private_z[i + 1] = private_z[i] + dt / 6.0 * (zK1 + 2.0 * zK2 + 2.0 * zK3 + zK4);
                           
            private_u[i + 1] = private_u[i] + dt / 6.0 * (uK1 + 2.0 * uK2 + 2.0 * uK3 + uK4);
            private_v[i + 1] = private_v[i] + dt / 6.0 * (vK1 + 2.0 * vK2 + 2.0 * vK3 + vK4);
            private_w[i + 1] = private_w[i] + dt / 6.0 * (wK1 + 2.0 * wK2 + 2.0 * wK3 + wK4);

        }
            
    
#pragma omp critical(sec)
            {
                    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                    {
                        u[j] += private_u[j];
                        v[j] += private_v[j];
                        w[j] += private_w[j];
                                       
                        x[j] += private_x[j];
                        y[j] += private_y[j];
                        z[j] += private_z[j];
                    }
            }


    }
    endT= omp_get_wtime();
```

Second version

```
    double
        sum_x = 5.0,
        sum_y = 0.8 * (bz + Rp) / 2.0,
        sum_z = 0.8 * (bz + Rp) / 2.0,

        sum_u = -Vt,
        sum_v = 0,
        sum_w = 0;


    startT = omp_get_wtime();

    omp_set_num_threads(2);

#pragma omp parallel shared(x0, y0, z0, x, y, z, u, v, w) 
    {
        int rank = omp_get_thread_num();
        size = omp_get_num_threads();


        double
            uK1, uK2, uK3, uK4,
            vK1, vK2, vK3, vK4,
            wK1, wK2, wK3, wK4,
            xK1, xK2, xK3, xK4,
            yK1, yK2, yK3, yK4,
            zK1, zK2, zK3, zK4,
            x1, x2, x3, x4,
            y1, y2, y3, y4,
            z1, z2, z3, z4;


#pragma omp for private(i) reduction(+: sum_x, sum_y, sum_z, sum_u, sum_v, sum_w)
        for (i = 0; i < N ; i++)
        {


            x[i] = sum_x;
            y[i] = sum_y;
            z[i] = sum_z;

            u[i] = sum_u;
            v[i] = sum_v;
            w[i] = sum_w;

            x1 = sum_x;
            y1 = sum_y;
            z1 = sum_z;

            getK1K2K3K4(x0, y0, z0, epsm, sig, x1, y1, z1, &uK1, &vK1, &wK1);

            xK1 = sum_u;
            yK1 = sum_v;
            zK1 = sum_w;

            x2 = x1 + dt / 2.0 * xK1;
            y2 = y1 + dt / 2.0 * yK1;
            z2 = z1 + dt / 2.0 * zK1;


            xK2 = xK1 + dt / 2.0 * uK1;
            yK2 = yK1 + dt / 2.0 * vK1;
            zK2 = zK1 + dt / 2.0 * wK1;

            getK1K2K3K4(x0, y0, z0, epsm, sig, x2, y2, z2, &uK2, &vK2, &wK2);


            x3 = x1 + dt / 2.0 * xK2;
            y3 = y1 + dt / 2.0 * yK2;
            z3 = z1 + dt / 2.0 * zK2;


            xK3 = xK1 + dt / 2.0 * uK2;
            yK3 = yK1 + dt / 2.0 * vK2;
            zK3 = zK1 + dt / 2.0 * wK2;


            getK1K2K3K4(x0, y0, z0, epsm, sig, x3, y3, z3, &uK3, &vK3, &wK3);

            x4 = x1 + dt * xK3;
            y4 = y1 + dt * yK3;
            z4 = z1 + dt * zK3;

            xK4 = xK1 + dt * uK3;
            yK4 = yK1 + dt * vK3;
            zK4 = zK1 + dt * wK3;

            getK1K2K3K4(x0, y0, z0, epsm, sig, x4, y4, z4, &uK4, &vK4, &wK4);


                sum_x += dt / 6.0 * (xK1 + 2.0 * xK2 + 2.0 * xK3 + xK4);
                sum_y += dt / 6.0 * (yK1 + 2.0 * yK2 + 2.0 * yK3 + yK4);
                sum_z += dt / 6.0 * (zK1 + 2.0 * zK2 + 2.0 * zK3 + zK4);

                sum_u += dt / 6.0 * (uK1 + 2.0 * uK2 + 2.0 * uK3 + uK4);
                sum_v += dt / 6.0 * (vK1 + 2.0 * vK2 + 2.0 * vK3 + vK4);
                sum_w += dt / 6.0 * (wK1 + 2.0 * wK2 + 2.0 * wK3 + wK4);

        }

    }
    endT= omp_get_wtime();
```

Results are bad. I think the problem is in these lines

```
            x1 = sum_x;
            y1 = sum_y;
            z1 = sum_z;


            xK1 = sum_u;
            yK1 = sum_v;
            zK1 = sum_w;
```

How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Numerical integration methods such as Runge-Kutta are *sequential* methods, where each iteration output is the input to the next iteration. You can't calculate the states in parallel since each state needs the previous state solution as an input. E.g., take these first lines from the loop:

```
    x1 = private_x[i];
    y1 = private_y[i];
    z1 = private_z[i];
```

These are used in your RK4 code to eventually calculate the next states:

```
    private_x[i + 1] = private_x[i] + dt / 6.0 * (xK1 + 2.0 * xK2 + 2.0 * xK3 + xK4);
    private_y[i + 1] = private_y[i] + dt / 6.0 * (yK1 + 2.0 * yK2 + 2.0 * yK3 + yK4);
    private_z[i + 1] = private_z[i] + dt / 6.0 * (zK1 + 2.0 * zK2 + 2.0 * zK3 + zK4);
```

But you have no reason to believe that in this parallel computation environment the private_x[i], private_y[i], and private_z[i] are actually computed yet. You are using garbage as input to the calculations, and you get garbage out.

You *must* do the iterations in sequence starting from the first one for the RK numerical schemes (Euler, Modified Euler, RK4, etc.) to work.

Comment: So, I can't parallelize this method, right?
I have a serial version, it works but for a long time. What would you advise me?

Comment: @AlexKh if you want advices on how possibly optimize your code, please post the sequential version, along the compilation options you are using (preferable in a separate question, but then put the link here). Something that *could* reduce the runtime: instead of using separate arrays or variables for x, y, z, u, v, w... use instead arrays of length 6, so that the compiler has chances to vectorize some operations.

Comment: @Alex Kh: Correct, you can't parallelize initial condition numerical integration solvers if the derivative function depends on the state. If you need your code to run faster you might look into different integration methods or adaptive step sizing. However, at some point you simply may need to accept the fact that some computations take a long time to complete.

Comment: @James Turs: It is sad. Thanks for the explanation..